# Join data by interval from another dataset (non-equi joins) [R]

Tags: r, non-equi-join

I am trying to `aggregate` `(FUN = mean)` the dataset **df1** by intervals of `df1$depth` from the dataset **df2** (`df2$minDepth` & `df2$Depth`) and that by `group` (**Station and Transect**) in order to join them by the column **depth, Station and Transect**. The problem is the max depth depends of the station, therefore from one group of data to another the interval can be 100-200 or 100-175, which make it quite complex.

e.g. if for **df2** the interval from a given station in a given transect is 400-1000, I would like the temperature from **df1** being aggregate from depth >400 to <= 1000.

Another possibilities would be to replicate the rows of **df2** with a `df2$minDepth + 0.5` until reaching `df2$maxDepth` value and then join by depth.

In both case I do not really know how to proceed.

```
df1 <- structure(list(Transect = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Station = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), temperature = c(0.0904, 
0.15, 0.7691, 0.0146, -0.3466, 1.9339, -0.0583, 0.208, -0.0755, 
1.9752, 2.0051, 1.9778, 1.9825, 3.3611, 2.3119, 0.2727, 0.0849, 
2.4664, 2.6563, 1.2256, 1.4938, 1.2118, 3.561, 2.0338, 1.8384, 
1.2348, 1.9761, 0.0472, 1.9731, 1.967, 0.0832, 1.9593, 1.6035, 
-0.5551, 2.0336, 0.2156, -0.1609, 0.1558, 0.2346, -0.4225, 1.9736, 
-0.0274, 1.9396, 1.1732, 2.0147, 1.4887, -0.0349, 1.4741, -0.1417, 
1.0949, 2.6406, 1.0877, 1.8169, 2.5692, 2.4662, -0.2685, 1.9774, 
1.9705, 2.0462, -0.1153, -0.6441, -0.8629, 1.9899, 1.6423, 1.541, 
-0.2768, 2.4161, 1.9753, 2.6955, 0.5983, -0.2354, -0.8856, -0.923, 
0.2718, 1.9774, 1.1851, 2.7037, -0.8477, 2.5275, -0.6093, 1.3051, 
2.0382, 2.4863, 1.3012, 1.9462, 2.0294, 1.9392, 1.421, 1.9744, 
1.9761, -1.0952, 1.5835, 2.6097, -0.3529, 1.9355, 1.9773, -0.743, 
2.603, 1.5249, -0.8462, 0.4651, 1.5508, -1.2618, -1.5018, -1.686, 
1.3767, 1.7305, 1.4991, 1.5003, 0.8662, 1.6691, -0.2488, 1.3982, 
1.6882, -1.6824, -1.4222, 0.9335, -1.5617, 1.3818, 0.2459, 1.7215, 
-1.677, -1.0255, 1.3761, 1.1095, 0.5204, 1.7848, -1.5796, 0.424, 
-1.5652, 1.3739, 3.9624, 1.5481, 1.1437, -1.5125, -1.6832, 1.4667, 
0.6127, 1.475, 1.4825, -0.6471, 1.0726, -1.6796, 1.1914, -1.2973, 
-1.6244, 0.6191, 1.1524, 1.6302, -1.4496, 0.7461, 0.6422, 2.7357, 
1.0529, 0.6229, 0.8845, 1.0181, -1.5218, 1.0376, -0.1418, 1.005, 
0.98, 2.7239, -1.5238, 0.9606, 0.8511, 0.7578, 1.013, 1.0136, 
6.0901, 0.2868, -1.5776, -0.2276, 2.6903, -1.3518, 1.0335, 0.7362, 
0.4402, 0.8468, 0.2621, -0.0475, 0.9451, -1.4984, 0.7847, 2.598, 
0.6331, 0.9527, 0.6488, 0.6407, 0.6129, -1.5152, 0.3581, 1.0337, 
0.9938, 0.9142, 1.0187, 0.85, 0.6053, -0.8318, 0.7135), depth = c(161.9, 
176.7, 30.5, 66.3, 128.3, 420.5, 61.1, 180.7, 77.1, 934.5, 474.5, 
500.5, 768.5, 6.7, 8.5, 187.5, 157.9, 4.5, 32.7, 272.5, 37.9, 
40.7, 13.1, 446.5, 406.5, 276.5, 794.5, 59.1, 818.5, 722.5, 152.3, 
526.5, 362.5, 117.1, 444.5, 56.5, 95.1, 177.1, 46.5, 87.1, 908.5, 
143.1, 666.5, 242.5, 432.5, 338.5, 141.9, 342.5, 79.1, 208.5, 
29.1, 204, 408, 37.4, 39, 170.7, 922, 702, 438, 178.6, 146.2, 
108.4, 484, 366, 348, 168.7, 44.7, 890, 22.6, 18, 171.9, 126.9, 
100.1, 205.7, 938, 264, 23.6, 109.2, 43.9, 147.4, 280, 436, 41.1, 
276, 550, 454, 574, 312, 876, 902, 85, 354, 35.6, 165.8, 658, 
920, 81.3, 31.5, 320, 132.5, 8.8, 242.1, 101.2, 30.5, 64.4, 321.8, 
205.9, 273.1, 270.3, 179, 197.1, 145.2, 304.9, 200.7, 68.4, 94.8, 
170.6, 82.4, 317.4, 151.8, 227.7, 66.8, 115.6, 321, 176.3, 67, 
213.2, 35.5, 153, 34.7, 323, 25, 246.5, 176.7, 88.8, 64.8, 292.7, 
161.8, 287.9, 279.5, 15.9, 53, 59.6, 180.3, 98.4, 70.4, 162.6, 
177.9, 195.5, 93.2, 298.2, 238.2, 365.5, 475.4, 223.4, 346.6, 
422.9, 78.8, 453.7, 126.6, 395.8, 377.8, 387.5, 75.6, 372.2, 
334.6, 307, 405.6, 413.2, 4.2, 143.8, 42.2, 97.5, 333.5, 90.4, 
446.1, 294.2, 171.4, 333, 157.5, 129.8, 361.8, 56, 313.8, 299.5, 
229.8, 367.8, 240.6, 235, 11.4, 77.6, 159.4, 445.7, 388.2, 357.4, 
427.3, 334.2, 211.8, 109.4, 285.4)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
df2 <- structure(list(Transect = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "6", 
"7"), class = "factor"), Station = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("1", "10", "11", 
"12", "14", "16", "17", "18", "2", "20", "22", "23", "24", "3", 
"4", "5", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), minDepth = c(100L, 
100L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 50L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 50L, 50L, 25L, 
25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 100L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 
100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 400L, 400L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 100L, 100L), 
    maxDepth = c(175L, 175L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    225L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 
    200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 
    300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 50L, 25L, 
    25L, 25L, 480L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 100L, 
    200L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 850L, 850L, 50L, 50L, 200L, 200L, 
    200L), `Average length(µm)` = c(2925, 4233.33333333333, 
    4367.5, 4367.5, 4367.5, 3360, 3360, 3360, 4404.16666666667, 
    2497.22222222222, 2497.22222222222, 2497.22222222222, 3277.5, 
    3277.5, 6593.75, 4525, 2822.5, 2822.5, 2822.5, 4393.75, 1992.5, 
    1992.5, 2012.5, 2012.5, 2012.5, 2902.5, 2902.5, 2902.5, 3232.5, 
    3232.5, 6675, 6675, 6675, 4325, 4325, 2064.28571428571, 5391.66666666667, 
    1925, 1925, 1925, 4162.5, 4216.66666666667, 2432.5, 2432.5, 
    3475, 2500, 3250, 3283.75, 3962.5, 4329.16666666667, 4412.5, 
    4412.5, 4412.5, 5252.5, 5252.5, 3550, 6400, 2345, 2345, 2345
    )), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need are non-equi joins to match the depth in `df1` with the depth ranges in `df2`. I can think of 2 approaches which can handle this.

The `sqldf` package allows you to use SQL syntax to manipulate data frames.

```
library(sqldf)

# get the unique intervals from df2
intervals <- unique(df2[,1:4])

# join the intervals to df1
new_df1 <- sqldf('select df1.*, i.minDepth, i.maxDepth from df1 left join intervals i 
                 on (df1.Transect=i.Transect and df1.Station=i.Station 
                        and df1.depth > i.minDepth and df1.depth <= i.maxDepth)')


# calculate mean temperature using the intervals to group
sqldf('select Transect,Station,minDepth,maxDepth,avg(temperature) as mean_temp
        from new_df1
        group by Transect, Station, minDepth, maxDepth
        order by Transect, Station, minDepth, maxDepth')
```

The `data.table` package also allows non-equi joins.

```
library(data.table)

# convert data frames to data.table
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)

# get unique intervals rom dt2
intervalsdt <- unique(dt2[,1:4])

# join the intervals on to dt1
new_dt1 <- intervalsdt[dt1,  
                       .(Transect, Station, minDepth=x.minDepth, maxDepth=x.maxDepth, temperature), # the minDepth=x.minDepth and maxDepth=x.maxDepth are needed to take these values from the left data table (dt1), otherwise you will get the matched data (both equal to depth from intervalsdt)
                       on=.(Transect==Transect, Station==Station, minDepth<depth, maxDepth>=depth), # this is equivalent to the ON ... part of a SQL join
                       nomatch=NA] # nomatch=NA makes this into a right join so it keeps the rows which dont fall within an interval

# calculate mean temperature
new_dt1[, .(mean_temp=mean(temperature)), by=.(Transect, Station, minDepth, maxDepth)
        ][order(Transect, Station, minDepth, maxDepth)]
```